# Segue to view with Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

My app has a walkthrough at the start of it.

It is VC1 -> VC2 -> VC3 with custom segues between each VC.

The main view of my app is a series of view controllers with a navigation controller.

Nav Controller (root view of) -> VC4 (Main) -> VC5

The app delegate determines whether the initial view controller is VC1 or the Nav Controller

My question is how do I segue (or push) from VC3 to VC4 and then have the navigation controller work so I can push via the navigation controller to VC5? Once the app has segued to VC4 it will never need to go back to VC3.

The nav bar is hidden in the entire app.

Cheers,

Andy

Answer (score 0):

Create a segue in between the view controllers, not linked to a button, and set their identifiers in storyboard to something different for each one. You can then use this code to perform segues programmatically:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourIdentifier" sender:self];
```

Using this, you can control where and when the segues happen. From your question I can't exactly discern *what* it is you want to do, but I hope that this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I'm able to segue from my walkthrough screens to the main view controller using performSegueWithIdentifier, but since the walkthrough screens don't have a navigation controller, when I segue to my main view controller, I can't then push to another VC (VC5) using the navigation controller, as I don't think the navigation controller has been introduced. So how can I segue from the walkthru to the main VC (this is the view with the navigation controller)

Comment: Why not embed them all in a navigation controller and just hide the nav bar on some, so you can use a push with all of them?

Comment: I originally did that, but I wanted to have a different animation so I used a custom segue instead. I can always switch back to that - but interested as to how you can segue to a VC with its own navigation controller